# Ways to model the farmer, goat, cabbage, wolf puzzle?

Tags: alloy

I am cataloging various ways of modeling the farmer, goat, cabbage, wolf problem.

Below are two ways to model the problem. Are there other, reasonable, ways to model it?

One model defines a *set* of River objects. Each River object represents a snapshot of the River and its two sides after the farmer has done a ferry.

```
sig River {
    side1: set Item,
    side2: set Item
}
```

Another model has *one* River object. The items on the two sides of the River vary over time.

```
one sig River {
    side1: Item -> Time,
    side2: Item -> Time
}
```

What are other, reasonable, ways to model the farmer, goat, cabbage, wolf problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine the puzzle as an ordered series of situations where a situation contains location-item pairs.

```
open util/ordering[Situation]

abstract sig Location {}
one sig SideA, SideB extends Location {}

abstract sig Item {}
one sig Goat, Cabbage, Wolf, Farmer extends Item {}

sig Situation {
  l_i: Location -> Item
}
```

Puzzle rules are easy to form then:

```
// in the initial situation everyone is on SideA
one s: Situation & first |  all i: Item | s.l_i.i = SideA
// in the final situation everyone is on SideB
one s: Situation & last  |  all i: Item | s.l_i.i = SideB

// in all other situations the locations of the goat/wolf and the cabbage/goat must be diffent, except when the farmer is also there
all s: Situation - first - last |  (s.l_i.Goat != s.l_i.Cabbage) or s.l_i.Goat = s.l_i.Farmer
all s: Situation - first - last |  (s.l_i.Goat != s.l_i.Wolf)    or s.l_i.Goat = s.l_i.Farmer
// further puzzle constraints ...
```

I'm curious if there's a more compact way to refer to the first item in an ordering than

```
one s: Situation & first
```

Comment: In review of the question it seems the variations on describing this simple puzzle wouldn't be significantly different. Even in my answer what I call 'situation' is effectively a snapshot in time, describing who is where, and my model is not very different from those in the post. There's another way to introduce variety, though. Thanks to the ingenuity of Alloy, the game could be easily extended to deal with more animals and pieces of food, two or more farmers and boats, even more than one river and more than one set of participants with shared boats.